# Sampling custom probability density function in R

Tags: r, probability-density, density-plot

Through the dwp package, I got the probability density function which describes my original data. The function itself is given within the list, so I can see the fitted parameters by checking that particular list element:

```
> Kbatmod$xep02
Distribution: xep02
Formula: ncarc ~ log(r) + I(r^2) + offset(log(exposure))

Parameters:
           b0            b2 
-0.8396640654 -0.0004653923 

Coefficients:
  (Intercept)        log(r)        I(r^2) 
-2.1154557406 -0.8396640654 -0.0004653923 

Variance:
              (Intercept)        log(r)        I(r^2)
(Intercept)  3.034712e-01 -1.111308e-01  4.550014e-05
log(r)      -1.111308e-01  4.608998e-02 -2.451855e-05
I(r^2)       4.550014e-05 -2.451855e-05  2.531856e-08
```

Now I want to sample that function to plot the point cloud (locations around the 0,0). Direction or bearing is going to be sampled as random numbers between 0 and 360. But distances need to fit to this fitted xep02 function. I can't find the function which would do that in the dwp package, even though its manual uses this kind of density point clouds to explain how it works.

I tried the RVCompare package, and the function sampleFromDensity.
But I keep getting errors, and I believe it is because of how I'm giving it the xep02 function.

```
> dwpPDF <- Kbatmod$xep02
> 
> PDFsamples <- sampleFromDensity(dwpPDF, 100, c(0,100))
Error in density.default(X[[i]], ...) : 
  need at least 2 points to select a bandwidth automatically
```

Can someone help me how to "translate" what dwp package gave me into input for RVCompare?

Aim is to obtain a vector with 100 distances which fit the xep02 PDF, add a vector of 100 random selected bearings, and then plot these in ArcGIS to overlay with predefined polygons and see how many points fall within these polygons.

Comment: `sampleFromDensity` is expecting a function as its first argument. Did you try the `ddd` function? E.g., `sampleFromDensity(function(x) ddd(x, dwpPDF),...`

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much!! Exactly as you suggested it.

Comment: Great! I'll add it as an answer in case someone comes across this in a search.

Answer (score 0):

`sampleFromDensity` is expecting a function as its first argument. You can accomplish this with the `ddd` function:

```
sampleFromDensity(function(x) ddd(x, dwpPDF), 100, c(0,100))
```